# Extending/Inheriting Tomcat Projects

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

We are developing webapps with Eclipse + Tomcat plugin. We recently started a new app which will run on Facebook and StudiVZ (FB competitor in Germany). Since the functionality of the app will be 95% the same we split the code into separate Eclipse projects (app-core, app-facebook, app-vz). The -core project is source-linked into the -facebook and -vz projects in Eclipse. We are also using Hudson for CI and made ant scripts that import the code from the -core project before building. So basically we tried to inherit on a project level.

The described method has some flaws:

- Versioning is complicated
- The -core project does not run standalone, which makes automatic testing partly impossible
- We need to modify some models where the -core projects classes depend on
- Other problems that make me think this is not the best solution

Does anyone have suggestions for a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to split your project into 3 or more parts and then establish dependencies via Java Build Path. You need to clean up the dependencies between the projects. If you need to configure your core components depending on whether it is a -facebook or a -vz project, you might need to separate configuration, maybe even use Spring or similar dependency injection framework.

When trying to introduce reuse into web-based Java projects, usually the problems arise in the UI code. Not many frameworks were built with this approach in mind.

Comment: As to UI troubles: at least JSF supports including/reusing templates which are delivered by external JARs.

Comment: @BalusC When we were figuring a common platform for applications in our business unit, we started with Struts 1.2. The way to reuse Struts UI was so hokey, we could do it only WSAD, not in Eclipse. We played a bit with JSF and ended up with GWT. At that time there was no MVC support frameworks for GWT, so we had to roll our own. Now we are able to share not just widgets but complete UI for reusable modules of our applications.

Answer (score 2):

There are a wealth of build tools available for Java that address dependency management and versioning specifically.  Many of these integrate with Hudson and Eclipse.

I'd suggest looking at [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) and how it does dependency management as a good starting point.  Even if you don't use [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) itself, many of the solutions out there build on Maven's dependency management mechanism.  Something like [Apache Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) allows you to use maven dependency management, but still use your own custom Ant scripts; whereas something like [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/) is wholesale replacement.

Comment: Gradle allows imports of Ant scripts. So it is NOT a wholesale repalcement

Answer (score 0):

I don't use/hate Eclipse[1], but can point to how we deal with a similar problem.

We use Maven with IntelliJ. In particular, both of these support [modules](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Multi-modules+projects) which have defined internal dependencies. In your case it could be *-fb* and *-vz* modules depending on *core*, or you can split core into smaller parts (such as *DAO*, *business logic*, etc.).

When compiling, deliverables of "upper" modules would be used to build "lower" modules.

Let's go over points/flaws you have raised:

- versioning is no longer a problem as everything sits under the same root of Subversion/GIT/VCS of your choice
- Why is that a problem? Certainly this shouldn't be an issue for unit tests as how I understand TDD, these should not require complex environments. For automated tests, you would have to test the core API (as this is the interface between core and everything else, right?) hence this shouldn't require any fronted stuff?
- you need to explain your other points to tell why you don't like it

  1. It is against Geneva convention to ask a developer to use anything other than IDE of his/her choice.